# Regex Multiline Pattern and Substitution Replacement

Tags: text-processing, sed, find, osx, regular-expression

For a migration process, I need to do some replacement in my bash script.

So in my .txt files, I have these references for example:

```
{{Info DOC
|author= ME
|company= MY COMPANY
|classification= RESTRICTED
}}
```

What I need to do is to edit all these occurrences with this format:

```
=== Info DOC ===
|author= ME
|company= MY COMPANY
|classification= RESTRICTED
```

1. {{ }} removed.
2. === === added on first line.

---

I tried to do a is to build sed regex to do a substitution

```
sed -i -e 's/{{Info DOC/=== Info DOC ===/g' test_file.txt
```

So, it's working as expected, but a can't do the same for string "}}" as it will match more things as expected.

I'm trying to achieve it with something like this:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec perl -i -pe 's/{{Info DOC\(.*\)}}/=== Info DOC ===\n\1/g' {} \;
```

If you have some clues for me, it will be great ! Thank you all !

**Final Solution:** (thank you @Sundeep)

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec perl -i -0777 -pe 's/\{\{(Info DOC)(.*?)\}\}\n/=== $1 ===$2/sg' {} \;
```

PS: I'm on MacOS system and use bash v4

Comment: what's your `sed --version`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest unable to use this arg to view version of sed on macOS :/

Comment: @don_crissti sorry, just clarified my first post. Yes I want to get rid of opening and closing braces and edit first line by adding "= " characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

```bsh
$ # tested on GNU-sed, not sure of syntax for other versions
$ sed '/{{Info DOC/,/}}/ { s/{{\(Info DOC\)/=== \1 ===/; /}}/d }' ip.txt
=== Info DOC ===
|author= ME
|company= MY COMPANY
|classification= RESTRICTED
```

- `/{{Info DOC/,/}}/` from line containing `{{Info DOC` to line containing `}}` (see [Range Addresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Range-Addresses) for details)

  - `s/{{\(Info DOC\)/=== \1 ===/` transform as needed
  - `/}}/d` delete this one
  - rest of the lines won't be changed

With `perl`

```bsh
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/\{\{(Info DOC)(.*?)\}\}\n/=== $1 ===$2/sg' ip.txt
=== Info DOC ===
|author= ME
|company= MY COMPANY
|classification= RESTRICTED
```

- `-0777` slurp entire file, so this solution not suited for too big an input file
- `.*?` non-greedy matching
- `s` modifier to allow `.` to match newline character as well

Comment: sed suggestion works great on single file, if I want to use it on multiple files with ‘find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec gsed '/{{Info DOC/,/}}/ { s/{{\(Info DOC\)/=== \1 ===/; /}}/d }' {} +‘ seems not working. (gsed is used on macOS for GNU SED)

Comment: could you elaborate what is not working? is there an error? file not changed? etc...  for inplace editing, you'd need to add `-i` option...

Comment: Sorry it's working great now, I option was misplaced during my tests, working as expected, thank you for your time !